# Get sub-strings from a string that are enclosed using some specified character

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, substring

Suppose I have a string

> Likes (20)

I want to fetch the sub-string enclosed in round brackets (in above case its 20) from this string. This sub-string can change dynamically at runtime. It might be any other number from 0 to infinity. To achieve this my idea is to use a `for` loop that traverses the whole string and then when a `(` is present, it starts adding the characters to another character array and when `)` is encountered, it stops adding the characters and returns the array. But I think this might have poor performance. I know very little about regular expressions, so is there a regular expression solution available or any function that can do that in an efficient way?

Comment: `string num = Regex.Match("Likes (20)", @"\d+").Value;`

Comment: @I4V: can you please explain your code? and how should I use it in my case? As I am not much familiar with regex.

Comment: Or you use just Substring with IndexOf? That's no regular expression but also very simple.

Comment: But the enclosed string might change dynamically. So how can I use this in that case? An example will be great.

Comment: "But the enclosed string might change dynamically." - this was not stated in your question.... be more specific, give more examples etc etc i.e. put some effort in

Comment: This is obvious as I said "Suppose" in my question. So it can be any string. Any ways I edited my question and added the note.

Comment: lol erm no, suppose you have a string "345", suppose it's null, suppose it's empty, suppose it's "(20)(30)", that's a lot of supposing... would it kill you to be more specific?

Comment: Can you elaborate on `Enclosed string might change dynamically`?

Comment: Please have a look at my edit.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva The fact the the number can change is fine! So long as the rest of the string remains static e.g. `Likes (2000000)` many of the solutions including my own will be perfect for you.

Comment: yup, the rest of the string will remain static.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva Then there is no problem, the answers already posted (for the most part) will achieve what you need

Comment: Now I have variety of options to test. Thanks to all of you. Just one last question before marking my answer. Which is more efficient? Regex or Split?

Comment: For such a small string I would say `Split` but I would say this is a micro optimization...

Comment: @Taemyr: I am getting a little confused here. I will try all of them and see which one is efficient. Thanks for your suggestion. :)

Comment: @Taemyr have you benchmarked each of the solutions posted here? Because I found that my own answer is slightly faster than Tim's: `0.04887438;` vs `0.0523943186`.. tested over 1,000,000 iterations in Release mode outside of IDE.

Comment: @DGibbs No I had not.  Your result surprises me.  Do you have any guess where the Tim's solution loses time?

Comment: @Taemyr Unfortunately I can't spend any more time on this but it would be good to know why you find it surprising

Comment: @DGibss, well finding the index and then taking the substring means one scan of the string for the character and then creating the new strings.  Split still has to scan the string, and create the new strings, in addition to creating the new class. - Presumably given your result it doesn't actually create the new string until you access it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't fancy using regex you could use [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx):

```
string foo = "Likes (20)";
string[] arr = foo.Split(new char[]{ '(', ')' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string count = arr[1];
```

`Count = 20`

**This will work fine regardless of the number in the brackets `()`**

e.g:

> Likes (242535345)

Will give:

> 242535345

Comment: This makes a lot of assumptions about well formedness. ")start(123)" gives start out.

Comment: The OP has already stated that the rest of the string is to remain static - `yup, the rest of the string will remain static`. In cases where the string is completely mangled such as `)start(123)` I would say that the OP has bigger problems on his hands...

Comment: No I only need numbers. As I said in my question `The substring will be a number from 0 to infinity`.

Comment: thanks @DGibbs and all of you who answered and responded to my question :)

Answer (score 1):

```
const string likes = "Likes (20)";
int likesCount = int.Parse(likes.Substring(likes.IndexOf('(') + 1, (likes.Length - likes.IndexOf(')') + 1 )));
```

Comment: Let me list the things wrong with this answer: **1.)** `string` doesn't contain a method `substring`, nor a method `indexOf`. **2.)** C# is a case sensitive language. **3.)** You are missing a a `)` bracket **4.)** You are missing a semi-colon `;` **5.)** When the above issues are corrected, this doesn't even return the right result - it gives `2` instead of `20`. -1

Comment: You are still missing a `)` from this

Answer (score 1):

For a strict matching, you can do:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^Likes\((\d+)\)$");
Match m = reg.Match(yourstring);
```

this way you'll have all you need in `m.Groups[1].Value`.

As suggested from I4V, assuming you have only that sequence of digits in the whole string, as in your example, you can use the simpler version:

```
var res = Regex.Match(str,@"\d+")
```

and in this canse, you can get the value you are looking for with `res.Value`

**EDIT**

In case the value enclosed in brackets is not just numbers, you can just change the \d with something like `[\w\d\s]` if you want to allow in there alphabetic characters, digits and spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Works also with pure string methods:

```
string result = "Likes (20)";
int index = result.IndexOf('(');
if (index >= 0)
{
    result = result.Substring(index + 1); // take part behind (
    index = result.IndexOf(')');
    if (index >= 0)
        result = result.Remove(index);    // remove part from )
}
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://ideone.com/FX4C9K)**</kbd>

Comment: @PaulZahra: Specify "won't work". What's wrong with `20` as result? Where is specified that this is possible and that he wants to extract all values and not just the first then?

Comment: How will it handle "(1(2)3)"?

Comment: @Taemyr: It will return `1(2`. I have never said that it's safe for every input. It requires a strict pattern (similar to regex). But if i can do things with string methods only i use them  since they are more efficient, more readable(for many people) and they allow to add additional logic inside (like logging).

Comment: Largely yes.  Especially when I don't catch that the original question has changed.

Comment: @Taemyr: I don't understand, this does still answer the current (modified) question.

Comment: I was merely highlighting the fact that he was not specific in his original unedited question, he in fact 'supposed' the string would be Like (20)... very ambiguous, although he has now been more specific in his edits.

Comment: Downvote comments (ie. my comment) are overrated, especially when they are not in sync with the current question.

Comment: Sadly people don't tend to adhere to SO rules, they vote as they feel like. IMHO it's helpful and so i give it +1 to combat the stupidity.

Answer (score 1):

Matching when the part in paranthesis is supposed to be a number;

```
string inputstring="Likes (20)"
Regex reg=new Regex(@"\((\d+)\)")
string num= reg.Match(inputstring).Groups[1].Value
```

Explanation:
By definition regexp matches a substring, so unless you indicate otherwise the string you are looking for can occur at any place in your string.

\d stand for digits.  It will match any single digit.

We want it to potentially be repeated several times, and we want at least one.  The + sign is regexp for previous symbol or group repeated 1 or more times.

So \d+ will match one or more digits.  It will match 20.

To insure that we get the number that is in paranteses we say that it should be between ( and ).  These are special characters in regexp so we need to escape them.

(\d+) would match (20), and we are almost there.

Since we want the part inside the parantheses, and not including the parantheses we tell regexp that the digits part is a single group.

We do that by using parantheses in our regexp.  ((\d+)) will still match (20), but now it will note that 20 is a subgroup of this match and we can fetch it by Match.Groups[].

For any string in parantheses things gets a little bit harder.

```
Regex reg=new Regex(@"\((.+)\)")
```

Would work for many strings.  (the dot matches any character) But if the input is something like "This is an example(parantesis1)(parantesis2)", you would match (parantesis1)(parantesis2) with parantesis1)(parantesis2 as the captured subgroup.  This is unlikely to be what you are after.

The solution can be to do the matching for "any character exept a closing paranthesis"

```
Regex reg=new Regex(@"\(([^\(]+)\)")
```

This will find (parantesis1) as the first match, with parantesis1 as .Groups[1].

It will still fail for nested paranthesis, but since regular expressions are not the correct tool for nested paranthesis I feel that this case is a bit out of scope.

If you know that the string always starts with "Likes " before the group then Saves solution is better.

Answer (score 1):

Even with Linq:

```
var s = "Likes (20)";
var s1 = new string(s.SkipWhile(x => x != '(').Skip(1).TakeWhile(x => x != ')').ToArray());
```

Comment: A lot less efficient and even less readable than pure string methods.

Comment: Sure, just another way to do the same.